# Connecting to trial instance of Dynamics 365 for Operations

Tags: azure, axapta, azure-logic-apps, dynamics-365-operations

I signed up for a trial version of Dynamics 365 for Finance and Operations. I am trying to connect to it using Azure Logic App and running into issues.

[image]

At first it seems like a redirect problem, which could possibly be related to redirect to HTTPS. However, if I add `https://` to the Instance name, then I get the 404 error.

```
{
  "status": 404,
  "message": "The remote name could not be resolved.\r\n     inner exception: An error occurred while sending the request.\r\n         inner exception: The remote name could not be resolved: 'https'\r\nclientRequestId: a3a434ce-9ce4-4fe3-a04b-ab9dded1ba73",
  "source": "dynamicsax-logic-cp-canadacentral.logic-ase-canadacentral.p.azurewebsites.net"
}
```

It seems like the connector does not understand `https`. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: I can seen that in designer the instances list on that subscription is shown as drop down to select. Are you trying to enter custom value there? Then it should be like source in the body message above.

Comment: Yes it's the custom value pointing to trial version of dynamics. When I set Instance value to value in `source` in body message I get 404 error.